# Astrology Software for Linux

Tags: linux, charts

Is there any astrology software for Linux? I have looked at [astrology_Linux](https://www.linuxlinks.com/astrology/) and I have tried the software in the list. But I have run into various issues; I am new to Linux and I don't like building from source or putting in new repos.

Note that I am aware that astrology charts can be done online like astrotheme. But I have found those sites too limited for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

openastro.org is easy to install. People seem to like it. I mean it is good, but I want more technical features, so I'm probably going to compile something.

Comment: openastro is no longer available 2022nov14.